# Is there any classical algorithm to transform one tree (or a graph) to another in minimal number of steps

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Let's say I have two graphs (trees in this case):

```
graph 1:
    root
        child_1
            leaf_1, leaf_2, leaf_3
        child_2
            leaf_1, leaf_2, leaf_4

graph 2:
    root
        child_1
            leaf_2, leaf_4
        child_2
            leaf_2, leaf_3
```

And I want to find the minimal sequence of steps to transform from `graph 1` to `graph 2`.
I have at least two options:

1. ```
    child_1.delete(leaf_1)
    child_1.delete(leaf_3)
    child_1.add   (leaf_4)

    child_2.delete(leaf_1)
    child_2.delete(leaf_4)
    child_2.add   (leaf_3)
   ```
2. ```
    child_1.delete(leaf_1)

    child_2.delete(leaf_1)

    root  .delete(child_1)
    root  .append(child_1)
   ```

So how do I find the minimal sequence in the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the **Graph Edit Distance (GED)** problem ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810170852/http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/2/vldb09-568.pdf)).

This is a NP-hard problem ([3](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xinbo_Gao2/publication/220654831_A_survey_of_graph_edit_distance/links/00b4952cac9f1d64a9000000/A-survey-of-graph-edit-distance.pdf)):

```
Therefore, graph edit distance can also be used to determine the subgraph isomorphism which is NP-Complete.
Then we can derive the following lemma.

Lemma 2.3. GED problem is NP-Hard.
```

Exact algorithms for computing the GED are generally based on the A* search algorithm ([3](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xinbo_Gao2/publication/220654831_A_survey_of_graph_edit_distance/links/00b4952cac9f1d64a9000000/A-survey-of-graph-edit-distance.pdf)):

> The most widely used method for computing exact graph
> edit distance is based on the well-known A* algorithm

There are also polynomial approximate/heuristic algorithms ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance)):

> Most of them have cubic computational time

For algorithm implementations, I suggest looking for *"graph edit distance"* at [Github](https://github.com/search?q=graph+edit+distance).

References:

- (1) [Graph edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance) (Wikipedia)
- (2) [A survey of graph edit distance](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810170852/http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/2/vldb09-568.pdf)
- (3) [Comparing Stars: On Approximating Graph Edit Distance](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xinbo_Gao2/publication/220654831_A_survey_of_graph_edit_distance/links/00b4952cac9f1d64a9000000/A-survey-of-graph-edit-distance.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. As I gather there is actually no **classical** algorithm in the same sense as there are reference implementations for Levenshtein distance for strings. With graphs it's still an active research field. But links are great, so I accept.